# can't keep socket open without corrupting file and blocking at while loop

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

i have a Java server and Android client.  the client sends 3 things to the server over TCP socket.  first is the file size in int,  second is a long that is serial number, and third it uses a while loop to send a pdf file.

all three files are sent successfully to the server, however to do this the outputstream (BufferedOutputStream) must be closed on both sides directly after the while loop. if this is not done then the pdf file that is sent to the server will be incomplete and corrupted.  and also the program will be blocked or frozen on the while loop of the server and no more program execution will take place.

the problem is that after closing the outputstreams in the client that also closes the socket and i can't send a response back to the client from the server.   also i can't open a new inputstream on the client side to receive this response back.

and there are 20 different android clients, so the same socket is needed to make sure that the return message gets back to the correct client it is intended for, as the server launches a separate socket object for each Android client that connects.

how do i keep the socket open? and still be able to send a complete file?

server code sample showing while loop

```
         @Override
        public void run() { // launch new thread

        fileSizeFromClient = dis.readInt();
        serialNumber = dis.readLong();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[fileSizeFromClient];

          while((count = dis.read(buffer)) > 0){
          bos.write(buffer, 0, count);
          }

         bos.close();

         } // end thread
```

client code sample showing while loop

```
             @Override
             public void run() { // launch new thread

             dos.writeInt((int)length); // sends the length as number bytes is file size
             dos.writeLong(serial); 

                int count = 0; // number of bytes

                while ((count = bis.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                    dos.write(bytes, 0, count);
                }
             dos.flush();
             dos.close();

             } // end thread
```

observations:

1 - calling close() on either BufferedOutputStream or DataOuputStream object will close the socket

2 - if outputStream.close() is not called in the client then in the server code it will be stuck or hung on the while loop and the execution of the thread will not continue, will be blocked, and the pdf file that was sent will be incomplete and corrupted

3 - if outputSteam.close() is not called in the server, then the server code will not be blocked or stuck as in #2 above, but the pdf file that was send will arrive incomplete or corrupted

4 - if close() is called on the outputstreams in both the client and the server directly after the while loop in each, then there is no blocking or problems in program execution in either client or server. and the pdf file always arrives in good condition.

EDIT:  am i going about this in a totally wrong direction?  is it better to close the socket after sending the pdf file and open a new socket?  if then how to open with the same android client that the earlier socket was connected to.  want to send a response message back the the same android client, not some other client.

Comment: I think you just need to flush the stream, no need to close the stream or socket. Basically by closing the stream you are essentially stopping writing to it. You should only close it after you get your response back

Comment: tried that but no effect, only closing the outputstream on the client side will avoid the corrupted and incomplete files.   still trying to find any way i can to do this but have not found it yet.

Comment: it is like the while loop is trapped in some sort of blocking, and there is no way to avoid even launched the while loops in separate threads but not effect.  must still close the outputstream on the client side for any file to be delivered complete and uncorrupted

Comment: Is this a filterstream? If so what is the base stream?  Is it a zip? For certain streams there is a finish() or end wrapper that has to be written. Close() will do this auto magically in that case I believe. Check the doc for the base stream

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the file size from the client before the while loop, you can modify your server code to read only the number of bytes of file size and close the PDF stream after receiving those bytes.

```
byte[] bufferPDF = new byte[fileSizeFromClient];
int count =0;
while (count!=fileSizeFromClient){
   bufferPDF[count]= disSocket.readByte();
   count++;
}
bosPDF.write(bufferPDF);
bosPDF.close();

/** Send response to client **/
dosSocket.write(responseBytes);
```

On the client side you try to read from the socket after sending the file and don't need to close the socket.

```
while ((count = bisPDF.read(bytes)) > 0) {
  dosSocket.write(bytes, 0, count);
}
dosSocket.flush();

while(disSocket.read(responseBytes)>0){
   //Process the response from server
}
```

Comment: tried it but if the socket is not closed on the client side then the pdf file that is sent arrives incomplete and corrupted

Comment: This code isn't correct. The loop condition needs to test the number of bytes read so far against the total length expected, and a length argument to read() is required, computed from the minimum of the buffer length and the number of bytes remaining to be read.

Comment: Yes the code wouldn't get you the desired result, the easier way to do this could be to read one byte at a time until you reach the file size. I'll edit the code.

Comment: ReadByte will throw either an EOFException or IOException, which from his original code, i am assuming he has already handled or will handle.